# Unable to style NavLink when using CSS isolation

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to make a Component for buttons in my Main Menu.

```
<NavLink href="@Href" title="@Title">
    <div class="main-menu-button">
        <img src="@IconUrl" />
        <div class="label">
            @Label
        </div>
    </div>
</NavLink>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string? Href { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string? IconUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I can't seem to target the NavLink in my css file. I've tried all of these different variations, but the button never changes color when active.

```
::deep a.active {
    background-color: red !important;
}

::deep .active {
    background-color: green !important;
}

::deep a .active {
    background-color: blue !important;
}

a.active {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

a .active {
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

I can see that the `active` class is present when I inspect element. I know my CSS isolation is working, because I am able to add styles that target the inner elements.

This problem is not limitted to the `active` class. I am also unable to target the NavLink element to set '`text-decoration:none` in css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Css isolation works by adding a custom scope identifier to all html elements of the component. As a result, the css you wrote

```
::deep a.active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

turns into something like the following

```
[b-zbwm49ki0i] a.active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

The above css, means `select all a elements that have an active class that are inside elements that have a b-zbwm49ki0i attribute`. In your example, there is no element with the custom scope identifier as a parent to the `Navlink`, so the css is not applied.
In other words, you need to wrap your `NavLink` in a `div` to be able to apply the css. This makes sure the link is in side an element with a custom scope identifier.

```
<div>
    <NavLink href="@Href" title="@Title">
        <div class="main-menu-button">
            <img src="@IconUrl" />
            <div class="label">
                @Label
            </div>
        </div>
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the surrounding div worked!