Blazor NavLink style with a class in CSS Isolation
I am trying to style NavLink in Blazor with a CSS class that I have in a CSS Isolation file for that razor file.  I just do not seem able to make any changes accept with global or inline styles.
sample.razor
<NavLink href="" class="cssLink">A Link</NavLink>

sample.razor.css
.cssLink {
  color: #10069f;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.cssLink:hover {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
}


You have two problems here. The first one is the CSS selector because simply writing cssLink as selector means there is an element of type cssLink. To select a elements by their class you have to place a dot before the class name so correctly would it be:
.cssLink {
  color: #10069f;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.cssLink:hover {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

The second problem is caused by the default behavior CSS isolation. By default these rules are only applied in their component which is the sense of isolation. To get around this you have to use the ::deep pseudo element to tell Blazor that it should apply these rule also for child components. You fixed CSS code looks this:
::deep .cssLink {
  color: #10069f;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

::deep .cssLink:hover {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
}


Thanks @Suiram, the missing dot was just a typo from me creating some example code. I think you have provided the resolution of ::deep as do recall this being mentioned in a tutorial I did but still when I try this it does not work.

Check whether you linked the bundled css code in you App.razor. If this also doesn't work it will be difficult to help from distance like this. The default Blazor template including sample pages uses CSS isolation so can try to compare it with yours to find what you misses.

You could try to add the NavLink in a div to be able to apply the css:
<div class="nav-container">
   <NavLink href="">A Link</NavLink>

</div>

css:
::deep a.active{
    color:brown;
}

Just make sure to put the .razor.css file in the same directory as the .razor file.
Result:

Refernce:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Thanks @Jalpa Panchal I think you have provided the answer this seems in line with this other article I this morning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581956/unable-to-style-navlink-when-using-css-isolation

@JustCoder yes test i perform i refer from the post link you have shared

@JustCoder i have made test with multiple solution at last this only worked
